# bitmap is empty when it is put in the array?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

in the Snake sample for Android, we push `bitmap` in the array, but bitmap contains nothing, ... what do you think?

```
public void loadTile(int key, Drawable tile) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mTileSize, mTileSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        tile.setBounds(0, 0, mTileSize, mTileSize);
        tile.draw(canvas);

        mTileArray[key] = bitmap;
    }
```

(edit: here is the link : [Snake sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Snake/index.html) )

Answer (score 0):

If the bitmap is being returned as null, then this means that something went wrong with the conversion from the File to Bitmap. Some possible solutions are the image was too big, it couldn't read the file, or the element you're pointing to in your array is null.

Comment: thanks JoxTraex, no i meant that `tile.draw(canvas);`draws the image, but we then push the `bitmap` in the array... but what i see is that `bitamp` is just an empty object, i was wondering why we push bitmap in the array, and not let's say: `tile` instead...